# Get tcp port from Sqlconnection

Tags: c#, ado.net

In my code, I have to get the TCP port of the source port I'm connection from. I only have a `SqlConnection(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)` object, what is the best way to get the port from my SqlConnection object in C#?

Comment: What do you mean "get tcp port" do you mean the port number of the server you are connecting to or the port of the source port you are connecting from?

Comment: Sorry my confusing, What I mean is the port of the source port I'm connection from, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SqlConnection.ConnectionString` and grab the Port from the `DataSource` object as this should be at the end of the `DataSource` seperated by comma (myDatabaseServer\Insatnce,1433")

Example:

```
  int port = int.Parse(sqlCon.ConnectionString.DataSource.Split(',').Last());
```

Don't forget to add error handling :)

Answer (score 0):

The SqlConnection.ConnectionString may contain the port in "Data Source". Have you tried running in "Debug" mode to trigger break points in your code? You should be able to inspect all the properties for that SqlConnection.

Not sure exactly what SqlConnection.RetrieveStatistics() returns, but you could inspect its return values as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, but they are not the answer I want.

Actually I want the port I'm connection from.
for example: With netstat I get connection information as following:
TCP  10.11.12.13:**3055**  9.10.11.12:1433   ESTABLSHED

I want to get port '3055' from SqlConnecton object.